# How to reconstruct distribution from the generating function

Tags: probability-distributions, generating-functions

Suppose $$F(x)=\sum_n p(n)x^n$$ is a generating function, and we have the expression for $F(x)$ explicitly. Then how we can get the expression for $p(n)$ from this generating function?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $p(n)=0$ for $n<0$,

$$p(n) = \frac{1}{n!}\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}F(x)\right|_{x=0}.$$

If your $F(x)=Ae^{Bx}x^C$, for $C$ a positive integer, then:

$$F(x)=A\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{B^nx^{n+C}}{n!},$$

giving

$$p(n)=A\frac{B^{n-C}}{(n-C)!},$$

for $n\geq C$ and $p(n)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: I am looking for a closed form expression for p(n).

Comment: @Anudeep: This is as good as it gets in the general case, unless $F(x)$ is a nice function like $1/(1-x)$, or $\sin(x)$, etc. Do you have an explicit form for $F(x)$?

Comment: The explicit form of $$F(x)=(1/s)e^{k_1/k_2(x-1)}x^{k_2/s}$$

Comment: R The explicit form of  $F(x)$ is $$F(x)=(1/s)e^{(k_1/k_2)(x-1)}x^{k_2/s}$$

Comment: @Anudeep: Is $k_2/s$ an integer? If yes, is it positive or negative?

Comment: $k_2/s$ is positive  real

Comment: for convenience u can treat $k_2/s$ to be positive integer.

Comment: @Anudeep: see edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It would be grateful if u can show me the steps in order to reach the given expression(or any reference)

Comment: @Anudeep: Just look at the Taylor expansion of $e^x$. The $x^C$ part just shifts the entire series over by $C$ units.